# How to define names with spaces and Characters

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I want excel to accept defined names with spaces and characters, because my program is linked to another database and I'm using C# OpenXML. I cannot use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`, or `VBA`. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Even if you could, you're asking for trouble. Excel probably isn't restricting the names to be whimsical but to prevent formulas from failing. Reformulate your problem so it doesn't depend on named ranges having illegal characters in them. You could set up a mapping between names without those characters and names with them, for example, or use a table. Excel isn't the problem (it's not intended to serve as a general database) -- your code is.

Comment: Rafalon, Everything is working well with my code, but i can not change the  define name. so i tried to put a defined name but change it's real value so.         
               string aa = name1.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("&", string.Empty);    DefinedName defineName = new DefinedName(){};
       defineName.Description = name1;defineName.Name = name1;
              defineName.Name.InnerText = aa;defineName.Name.Value = aa;           but the problem : each time i change the defineName or the defineName.value ; all the names changes as if they are linked to each others

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, even Table Name doesn't include a characters or spaces, in fact i'm getting my values from XML

Comment: i solved my problem using: Formula1 formula11 = new Formula1();
            formula11.Text = "INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($F$87,\" \",\"\"),\"&\",\"\"),\"-\", \"\" ))"; so i can remove spaces and characters.

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem using:
 Formula1 formula11 = new Formula1();
 formula11.Text = "INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($F$87,\" \",\"\"),\"&\",\"\"),\"-\", \"\" ))"; 
so i can remove spaces and characters. –